# Are raw levelDB files safe to use as a backup storage layer?

Tags: data-storage, leveldb

I have a service that stores data to LevelDB. To make backups I simply zip the entire data folder that LevelDB writes to and upload it to S3.

If I need to restore I just unzip the data and copy it back into the data folder and it seems to work great. I can also do this across Mac OSX and Linux Machines.

If I am running the same version of LevelDB on all machines is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: are writes being made to db while you are zipping? Or a process that uses leveldb is active? Because if the answer is yes there might be problems I think.

Comment: there might be rare race condition with files